# Need an extension cord with lever or magnetic switch

Tags: electrical, switch

I'd like to put an appliance in a tall pull out drawer in pantry.  Ideally I want it wired so that it only receives power if the drawer is pulled out - once the drawer is pushed in, power is cut to the appliance.

Thinking the easiest way to accomplish this is some sort of lever switch or magnetic switch in line on the extension cord that cuts power when engaged.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: Is this a high power appliance or can it get done with 12-24 volts DC?

Comment: @Harper it's for an 120v 1800w plug-in oven

Comment: Does the appliance not have a switch?

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're not going to want to use an extension cord for this.  This is all going to have to be done with an approved wiring method. So you'll want to used properly secured and supported wire, that's approved for permanent installation.

Depending on how much space is available, and if you can find a way to mount it.  A door jamb switch, would be one way to go. They're most commonly used, to turn lights on when closet doors open.

The other option, is to use a low voltage circuit to control the line voltage to the device.  With this approach, you'll need a transformer to step power down for the low voltage circuit.  You'll probably find 12V and 24V transformers easily. Then you'll need a relay that can switch the line voltage. You'll also have to make sure that the coil is rated at the low voltage you've chosen to use.

Make sure all you're connections are made in properly installed enclosures, and that all the wiring and devices are installed in accordance with their documentation and the NEC.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a limit switch. Something like a garage door but you would have to install it per NEC and, clearances and protection may become a problem.

Edit on rereading your question: I probably wouldn't put it on your extension cord. I would install it with the permanent wiring.

Comment: Thanks - hoping to find a limit switch that I could easily wire into an extension cord.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your power requirements and if you're into setting up smart home devices, you can accomplish this with an open/close sensor and a smart plug that cuts the power when the drawer is closed.

Comment: Thanks - should have added that I'd prefer a mechanical solution over a smart device to avoid possibility of it not shutting off every single time.